# Highcharts not loading when upgraded angular project to angular15 version

Tags: angular15, angular-highcharts

We have upgraded angular11 to angular15 version, before migration highcharts was working fine only, after migration charts not displaying and I am getting below error, Can anyone please help me to resolve this error.

[image]